# New washer hookup is overflowing

Tags: drain

We just had a new washer dryer hook up put on the first floor of our house. But immediately when the washer drains water, floods, the floor coming out of the drain. The plumber claims that it could be a bed vent but since the wall is now sealed up with sheet rock and spackle and painted. We really do not want to destroy the world. Is there something else we can do?[image]

Comment: I do not know those vents except from what I read on here, but having it inside of the wall, when they need replacing every so often, does not sound like the best of ideas.  A new vent should not have problems already, so maybe a clog in the drain your plumber did not know of, or they made a mistake.

Comment: To be clear water comes out where the washer hose goes into this pipe ?  I am not sure what the normal way to do it is.  Ours does not have a trap and air gap.  Maybe it just can't cope with the volume and pressure of water.

Answer (score 3):

There absolutely must be an access panel over the vent location large enough to replace it, so buy one, reference the picture, and cut a hole to put it in.

Not impressed with your plumber (this should have been tested before the wall was closed up, and the access should have already been there if using a mechanical vent. Also, the mechanical vent should have been higher than that.)